# Is this running time polynomial in the input size?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The input size of a certain algorithm is n^2+n*m. Its running time is O(m*n^3). Can the running time be considered polynomial in the input size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run time T(n,m) is said to be polynomial in the input size S(n,m) = n^2+n*m if there is a polynomial in S that is an upper bound on T(n,m).

Consider the polynomial S^2(n,m) = (n^2+n*m)^2 = n^4 + 2(n^2)n*m + (n^2)(m^2).  Since n^4 and (n^2)(m^2) are squares of positive integers they are positive, so S^2(n,m) > 2(n^2)n*m > n^3 * m.

Since T(n,m) is O(n^3 * m) and S^2(n,m) > n^3 * m we have T(n,m) is O(S^2(n,m)) hence run time is bounded by a polynomial in input size.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. It runs in `O(max{n,m}^4)`, which is polynomial time to the input which is smaller than `O(max{n^2,n*m}^2)`, which is quadratic in the size of the input.

Note: This assumes the input is of SIZE `n^2+n*m`, and not a *number* of this "size" - because a number can be represented as `log(n^2+n*m)` bits, which will get you only a [pseudo-polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) solution.